# Logical operator is jQuery

Tags: jquery, logical-operators

I have three file inputs as follows,

```
A File : <input type="file" name="AFile" id="AFile" />
B File: <input type="file" name="BFile" id="BFile" />
C File : <input type="file" name="CFile" id="CFile" />
```

I've used the following jQuery function to auto upload the 3 files all at once when selected,

```
$("#AFile" && "#BFile" && "#CFile").change(function() { 
document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
});
```

But as this works only for CFile selection and does not check if AFile and BFile are selected or not.

Logically I wanted it to work like `A AND B AND C`.

Comment: You should use a common class for all inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
var files = $("#AFile,#BFile,#CFile").change(function () {
    var count = files.filter(function () {
        return this.value.length
    }).length;
    if (count == files.length) {
        document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to detect that all 3 have changed.  Changing the selector will not add that functionality, so you have to do it yourself.  This should do the trick...

```
var files = {
    AFile: false,
    BFile: false,
    CFile: false
};

$("#AFile, #BFile, #CFile").on("change", function() {
    files[this.id] = !!this.value.length;
    for (var i in files) {
        if (!files[i]) return;
    }
    // they have all changed - do something here
});
```

That will flag when each of the inputs changes, and you can add whatever code you need at the end of the function, and it will only fire when all 3 have changed.

I put the loop in to check `files` so that you can easily extend it to add more file inputs if needed.

Comment: Not sure but just in case, i'd use: `files[this.id] = !!this.value.length;`

Comment: Good call, @A.Wolff.  That now handles the user clearing an input with the cancel button.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#AFile #BFile #CFile")
```

will be AND operator in selectors which mean select a element with all 3 ids i.e. `AFile` **AND**  `BFile` **AND** `CFile` while

```
$("#AFile, #BFile, #CFile")
```

mean OR operator, which means select all elements with id as `AFile` **OR** `BFile` **OR** `CFile`

Just a side note in HTML element should have single and unique id. `#AFile" && "#BFile" && "#CFile` (which means elements with id AFile AND BFile AND CFile) doesnt make sense in world of valid HTML

If you want to select all elements with id `#AFile, #BFile` and  `#CFile` then you should use

```
$("#AFile, #BFile, #CFile).change(function() { 
   document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
});
```

Comment: I've tried `$("#AFile #BFile #CFile")` but the form doesn't get submitted.

Comment: @Zedai I guess you want OR operator, so you should use `$("#AFile, #BFile, #CFile")`

Comment: I need the AND operator

Comment: @Zedai  `$("#AFile, #BFile, #CFile")` will select all elements with id as `AFile`, `BFile` OR `CFile`. AND operator means a element should have all 3 ids `AFile`, `BFile` AND `CFile`

Comment: I've implemented AND operator as you told, and Nothing happens. I am trying for AND operator.

Comment: I want AFile AND BFile AND CFile

Comment: OR operator will select all 3.  Check my updated answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51589/discussion-between-zedai-and-karna)

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma `,` to separate multiple selectors:

```
$("#AFile,#BFile,#CFile").change(function() { 
    document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
});
```

Comment: it acts like a or condition.. not an AND

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#AFile","#BFile", "#CFile").change(function() { 
document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#AFile , #BFile , #CFile").change(function() { 
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.addClass('changed');
   if($this.each(function(){
      return this.className == 'changed';
   }){
      document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
  }
});
```